# How to extract content of an archetype option, but fail if content is `none`?

Tags: smart-contracts

I have tried this:

```
entry makeOffer() {
  require {
    r_higherBid: topBid ? transferred > the : false otherwise "your Bid must be higher than current topBid";
  } effect {
    match lastBuyer with
    | some(a) -> const lastBuyerConst = a
    | none -> fail
    end
}
```

and this (in the place of the match)

```
const lastBuyerConst = lastBuyer ? the : fail
```

and many other less likely solution candidates.

Both return parsing errors and are invalid to the binding generator.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short answer is:

```
const lastBuyerConst ?= lastBuyer : "EXPECTED_SOME_BUYER"
```

`fail` is an instruction that takes anything as a parameter, hence it is called `fail()` or `fail("SOMETHING")` or `fail(("INVALID_AMOUNT", amount))` for examples.

I guess the following should work:

```
match lastBuyer with
| some(a) -> begin 
    const lastBuyerConst = a;
    // do something with a
    // ...
  end
| none -> fail() // do not forget parenthesis
end
```

but the `?= :`  syntax makes it much lighter:

```
const a ?= lastBuyer; // : "ERROR_MSG" is optional
// do something with a
```

More information here:

https://archetype-lang.org/docs/reference/instructions/localvariable#-get-option-assign-or-fail
https://archetype-lang.org/docs/reference/instructions/assignment#a--b--e
https://archetype-lang.org/docs/reference/instructions/control/#option
https://archetype-lang.org/docs/reference/instructions/divergent/#faile--t